# BMS vs Charging ICs

Tags: charging, discharge, bms

Does a BMS and charging IC both do the same functions or is a BMS strictly for monitoring the battery for any anomalies that could lead to a problem? However, doesn't a charging IC do the same thing in the charging process? Does this mean you only need one or both? One feature I need in my project is coulomb counting for charge and discharge, does only a BMS have this function (I assume I would need a BMS unless the charging IC can also monitor discharge)? Can you not control the c-rate with only a BMS?

Comment: Assume a pack of several cells in series. Does your charger IC see and check each one for under- and overvoltage?

Comment: I haven't picked a specific IC yet, but I would want one that can check each cell.

Comment: I looked at the BQ25720 datasheet but I couldn't figure out if it monitors them separately or just monitors for anomalies by using combined data from the whole pack.

Comment: There may be a blurred line between a charger and a BMS, but check the datasheets of 10 random charger ICs and 10 random BMS ICs and you should see a clear pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a BMS and charging IC both do the same functions

No.

Charging and battery management are two distinct functions, which are handled by two distinct devices:

- Charger: It limits the voltage and current to level appropriate for the **battery**. It has no knowledge of state of charge, and no knowledge of the voltage of each cell in the battery. It's a **regulator**, not a switch.
- BMS: monitors the voltage of each and every **cell**. If necessary, it interrupts the current. It measures the current in and out of the battery and from that it may evaluate the SoC. It's a **switch**, not a regulator.

Do not conflate charger and BMS: they are different.